# Does Guava have an overload that aborts the stream if it is too large?

Tags: java, servlets, guava

I have a servlet that clients will post xml or json data too.

Currently I am reading the posted content using Guava:

```
String string = CharStreams.toString( new InputStreamReader( inputStream, "UTF-8" ) );
```

I want to be able to abort my entire operation of reading the posted file if it is larger n in size.

Is there a way to do this using Guava or do I have to know implement my own function to do this?

Answer (score 5):

I don't see anything that aborts, but you can use [`ByteStreams#limit(InputStream, long)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#limit%28java.io.InputStream,%20long%29) to set a maximum number of bytes to read. The `InputStream` returned will simply return -1 on any `read(..)` that goes over the limit.

If you really want abort behavior, you could write your own `InputStream` wrapper that throws an exception if you go above some number of bytes read.